# How to draw a text with unicode character on the main window using Gosu Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, libgosu

I'm trying to output text to the main window with unicode character like that

```rb
def initialize                                  
  super 800, 800                         
  self.caption = 'Chess'    
  @font = Gosu::Font.new(self, Gosu.default_font_name, 100)
end

def draw                                   
  text = "Chess \u2658".encode('utf-8')
  @font.draw(text, 100, 100, 10, 1, 1, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
end
```

but the window displays only the 'Сhess' string without unicode symbol '♘' as supposed.

What I have tried so far:

- to change font name itself,  'Gosu.default_font_name' to 'Serif', 'Arial', 'Hack' - same result only 'Chess' string changes font but not displaying glyph
- use symbol '♘' instead of unicode code
- use .draw_markup, .draw_text, Gosu::Image.from_text.
- use different unicode code, for example with cyrillic letter '\u0416' it worked as supposed.
- use different encoding arguments.
- use different colors.

I looked for similar problems on the Gosu forum, but I could not find anything.

Comment: Sounds like the fonts you tried don't have the glyph for "♘". If it were a Unicode issue in general, U+0416 wouldn't work either.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, the issue was really in the font, I tried [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html), which includes glyphs for every printable code point and it works as supposed. If you answer this question I would mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a font that includes those Unicode characters or Gosu's internal font rendering code will return a 0 width image for drawing that character.

A font like: https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/chess

```
require "gosu"

class Window < Gosu::Window
  def initialize(*args)
    super

    @font = Gosu::Font.new(28, name: "Chess.odf")
  end

  def draw
    @font.draw_text("♘\u2658", 10, 10, 10)
  end
end

Window.new(100, 100, false).show
```